# Using DLLs in VBScript

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript

I've compiled C# code into a DLL, but have little experience with them. My C# code contains a class `HelloWorld` with a static method `Print()`. I'd like to use this DLL in VBScript to call the method `Print()`. I know this is base, but I'm using this as a test for a larger scale project that will be compiled to DLL in the end. What's the declare look like for that and how would the method call look?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call C# DLL function from VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769332/how-to-call-c-sharp-dll-function-from-vbscript)

Comment: I did check that link, but it doesn't quite get at what I want. I'm looking to dynamically load the dll at runtime through the VBScript from a given filepath rather than register with the server. Again, dlls are very new to me, so this may be what's happening in that answer, I just don't see it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Important**: Both methods will work only if the DLL exposes a COM interface.

If your dll is registered with the system, use `CreateObject` with it's ProgID.

```
Set myObject = CreateObject("MyReallyCoolObject.HelloWorld")
myObject.Print
```

If your object is not registered on the system, use `GetObject` with a path to the file containing your object.  Make sure your object exposes the proper interface. (The second parameter is optional.  Here you can provide a class name if your object exposes more than one.)

```
Set myObject = GetObject("C:\some\path\helloworld.dll", "appname.HelloWorld")
myObject.Print
```

Comment: I only succeded using regasm and then `CreateObject`. I never could make `GetObject` work. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: When I enter two parameters:
I got an error: _**ActiveX Component can't create object 'GetObject'.**_ When I enter only the first parameter: I got: _**File name or class name not found during Automation.**_

Comment: @HighTechProgramming15 Double check the path you have provided to the dll file.

Comment: Is this possibile without registering dll? I don't think so.

Comment: @BLuM It is if it exposes a COM interface.

Comment: How to ezpose it?

Comment: Could you please post a very simple example (about the dll and the vbscript as well) how to do this without the need to register the dll?

Comment: @kampi There already is. Please see the second part of the answer.

Comment: @Nilpo: you are right, but I meant the DLL side. Could you post a sample code is inside the DLL? I am interested in the GetObject way (dll without registration) Or do I have to make some changes? I always get the error people are describing in the previous comments.

Comment: I have the same results as @HighTechProgramming15 and cannot get to a working result with GetObject, but registering the DLL works. There has to be more to this?

Comment: @Nilpo I am trying to inject the VBScript into another application and receive error <'CreateObject' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.">. The error is the same while trying 'GetObject' too. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for [Registration-Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx).  This SO answer regarding the [Microsoft.Windows.ActCtx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765096/249624) should help specifically for VBScript.

Keep in mind that COM doesn't support static methods, so you'll have to make your Print method into an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

[How to call a .NET DLL from a VBScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79314/How-to-call-a-NET-DLL-from-a-VBScript)

Comment: Ok so that's how to register the DLL with the server/system as a whole, but how would I directly declare/call a dll in VBScript? I read the below link that seems to say it's possible, but how would that declare look if it were for a static method of a class?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106553

Comment: your link talks about visual basic. not vbscript. and your question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/769346/736170

Comment: That link does not answer my question. And apologies on the language mix-up. I do need this for VBScript, but I assumed there would be a similar process. I want to call the dll from my script without having to register with the server. It should be dynamically loaded at runtime from a file path.